# Using XMLUnit to compare two similar xml documents ignoring node text values

Tags: java, xml, maven, diff, xmlunit

I have two different XML documents below and please note that they are having the same basic structure (schema).

Source XML

```
<root>
    <name>String</name>
    <description>String</description>
</root>
```

Test XML

```
<root>
    <name>Test</name>
    <description></description> <!-- it is an empty node -->
</root>
```

And I build this snippet function to compare those two XML documents.

```
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Difference;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit;

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException,
            SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException {

        String strSource = "<root><name>String</name><description>String</description></root>";
        String strTest = "<root><name>Test</name><description></description></root>";

        Document docSource = stringToXMLDocument(strSource);
        Document docTest = stringToXMLDocument(strTest);

        boolean result = isMatched(docSource, docTest);
        if(result){
            System.out.println("Matched!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Un-matched!");
        }
    }
public static boolean  isMatched(Document xmlSource, Document xmlCompareWith) {
        XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
        XMLUnit.setIgnoreComments(true);
        XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true);

        XMLUnit.setNormalizeWhitespace(true);
        XMLUnit.setIgnoreDiffBetweenTextAndCDATA(true);

        Diff myDiff = new Diff(xmlSource, xmlCompareWith);
        myDiff.overrideDifferenceListener(new IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener());
        return myDiff.similar();
    }

public static Document stringToXMLDocument(String str) throws   ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    docBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(str)));

    return document;
}
```

And here is the Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
  <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I am expecting those two XML documents are the same, but the function always returns false. Are there any ways that I can ignore the node text value when comparing two XML structures. As you can see, I already used IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener, but I still got the problem.

Comment: I looked around a bit to agree there doesn't seem to be a builtin solution.   The problem I think isn't that you're not ignoring text node differences... it's that there's no text node at all in `<description></description>`.  Since XMLUnit 2.x is out with some significant changes https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/Migrating-from-XMLUnit-1.x-to-2.x ..maybe it'd help someone who really knew what they were doing if you indicated whether you'd be open to upgrading.

Comment: I am now overwriting IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener.differenceFound() to solve my case.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to provide a `DifferenceListener` of your own that delegates to `IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener` and in addition handles differences of type `HAS_CHILDNODES` and `CHILD_NODELIST_LENGTH`.

As @scott-kurz pointed out in the cmments there may not be any XML `Text` node at all, rather than an empty one, depending on your XML parser and its configuration.